# discord.py - Whenever someone deletes a message, send a message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I want to make it so that whenever someone deletes a message, I want to send a message straight after. I tried making some code that I thought would work, but it doesn't.

```
if message.delete():
    await message.channel.send("stop deleting")
```

Comment: Where does `message` come from? What function is this in?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the help of client events that is sent by discord when a message is deleted. Doc link - [on_message_delete](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#discord.on_message_delete)